# iPhone Submit to Apple - validate application does nothing

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I've submitted all the details into iTunes connect and my app status is 'prepare for upload'. However, after I build and archive and select 'validate application', nothing happens. Any ideas what could be causing that?

Comment: Same here. I don't think they'll fix it since xcode 4 is just about to be released.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Apple this?